# Content Lost If I left my Android phone for some time

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

I have developed a application in which a Expandable List have several EditText and Radio buttons.
Everything is working fine but once i enter the text in EditText and left my phone for some time then i lost the enetered text .....
So anyone can help me out on this issue.

Thanks in advance
RK

Comment: can u post ur code.. so we can give u better idea

Comment: could someone take your phone and delete it?

Comment: Implement an OnKeyListener and have it store your entered text in a persistant place.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand what happens when you "left your phone for some time":

- Another process can start (for example phone call), and OS will release some memory for it
- Phone can go to sleep for saving battery

Any way, you should save any changes that was made by user. Check [this article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for understanding where you can save user data. Usually it is `onStop` or `onDestroy` methods.